# Hibernate add new child(s) and update existings

Tags: java, hibernate, parent-child, hibernate-mapping, resteasy

I have multiple entities as `Chapter` to `Section` `OneToMany`(without join table).

`Section` to `Attachment` `OneToMany`(with join table).

I can add/update/delete `Sections` but can not delete attachments since attachments are exists in another table. I just need to manage join table.

Here are my entities:

Chapter.java

```
@Id
@Column(name = "CHAPTER_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer chapterId;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "chapter")
private List<Section> sections;
```

Section.java

```
@Id
@Column(name="SECTION_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer sectionId;

@Column(name="SECTION_DESC")
private String sectionDesc;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonBackReference
@JoinColumn(name = "CHAPTER_ID", updatable = false)
private Chapter chapter;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="SECTION_ATTACHMENT", 
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="SECTION_ID")}, 
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ATTACHMENT_ID")})
private List<Attachment> attachments;
```

Attachment.java

```
@Id
@Column(name="ATTACHMENT_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer attachmentId;

@Column(name="ATTACHMENT_NAME")
private String attachmentName;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="SECTION_ATTACHMENT", 
joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ATTACHMENT_ID")}, 
inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="SECTION_ID")})
@JsonBackReference
private Section section;
```

ChapterResource.class

```
@PUT
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/chapter/{chapterId}")
public Response updateChapter(@PathParam("chapterId") int chapterId, Chapter chapter) {
    return chapterService.updateChapter(chapterId, chapter);
}
```

ChapterServiceImpl.class

```
@Override
public Response updateChapter(int chapterId, Chapter chapter) {
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        dao.updateChapter(session, chapter);
        HibernateUtil.closeSession(session);
    } finally {
        HibernateUtil.closeSession(session);
    }
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Dao.java

```
public void updateChapter(Session session, Chapter chapter) {
    session.update(chapter);
}
```

I am creating new Chapter using a post call as

```
 {
        "sections":[
        {
            "sectionDesc":"first sectionDesc",
            "attachments":[{
                "attachmentId":1,
                "attachmentName":"attachment1.docx"
            }]
        }]
    }
```

when call GET chapter

```
{
    "chapterId":1,
    "sections":[
    {
        "sectionDesc":"first sectionDesc",
        "sectionId":1,
        "attachments":[{
            "attachmentId":1,
            "attachmentName":"attachment1.docx"
        }]
    }]
}
```

now I have to update using PUT as below

```
{
    "chapterId":1,
    "sections":[
    { //updating the existing attachment name
        "sectionDesc":"first sectionDesc",
        "sectionId":1, // this indicates existing section
        "attachments":[{
            "attachmentId":1,
            "attachmentName":"test.pdf" // change of attachmentName should not delete the section, but has to update the 
        }]
    },{ //adding new section here
        "sectionDesc":"new sectionDesc",
        // "sectionId":2, it should be auto increment during the insert
        "attachments":[{
            "attachmentId":10,
            "attachmentName":"sampleDoc.ppt"
        }]
    }]
}
```

when I make PUT call to my API, i am not getting any errors or warnings but the records are not getting changed in db as in put body.
Tried lot of trail and error but I could not figure out where i am going wrong.
can anyone help me if this achievable using `hibernate(5)`?

Comment: Try debug the method "updateChapter" to see if chapter was correct fulfilled.

Comment: yeah.. `chapter` in `updateChapter` is looks good as expected from JSON. What else can I try?

Comment: Can you add code where you are converting JSON to Entity...

Comment: I have added rest `resource`, and `service` impl where its automatically converts `json` to `Chapter` Entity

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate update should be used where we know that we are only updating the entity information.

try using

**merge()**  => preferred

or

**saveOrUpdate()**

More info [here](https://www.journaldev.com/3481/hibernate-session-merge-vs-update-save-saveorupdate-persist-example)

Comment: tried both of them, it's still same. new changes are not reflecting in DB.